# C++ Normal Distribution

Tags: c++, statistics, distribution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [erf(x) and math.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631629/erfx-and-math-h)
>   [Best library for statistics in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746364/best-library-for-statistics-in-c)

I am wondering if there is any standard way to implement a cumulative normal distribution function in C++. Or, is there any existing library for that task?

Can anyone recommend a good statistics library for C++, if there is any?

Thanks.

Comment: If you would be more specific about what kind of functionality you expect that library to have we could probably give better recommendations. Boost provides some basic tools, and then there are libraries like gsl or ROOT which go further. But it doesn't end there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the erf function (which is include in the standard math library, [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)).

```
CDF = 0.5 + 0.5 * erf(x/(sigma * sqrt(2.0)));
```

sigma = 1.0 for a normal distribution of course.

Comment: Ahh. Beat me to it. You don't need boost. All you need is `<cmath>`. Plus 1.

Answer (score 1):

Boost is as good as the standard. For more boost [maths/statistical](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/index.html).

Simple example for stand-alone C++ implementation of the cumulative normal distribution is available [Here](http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_phi.html)

Comment: You don't need Boost. Not really. The relation between `erf()` and `phi()` is a trivial one.

Comment: He is asking for libraries and Boost is one choice.

Comment: And the C math library is another. Why go to boost when this is already native?

Comment: @DavidHammen: `libm` isn't exactly famous for the many statistical tools it provides. But again, the question isn't well put.